# SonarQube Analysis Task Error After File Move

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have been using SonarQube analysis on a C# project as part of a TFS 2015/15 RC2 vNext build for ages which has been working fine.

A few days a go I refactored several aspects of code, this consisted of moving files into new folders within the same project, as opposed to class name changes etc.  Visual Studio didn't handle this correctly and I had to remove and re-add some files to the project on an individual basis.

Our analysis is now failing, when looking at the logs for the analysis task I can see the following error:

```
ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVe_-iOpE8SSKScA9O_3 java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  Original file OriginalFile{id=1363, uuid='ca50dc09-5d0b-4083-9e52-eb0f66361422', key='MIS:MIS:4E9625D2-557E-450C-90CC-A6B6FB57B6C9:Models/XXX/Grids/ProjectTeams/SmpProjectTeamFilterModel.cs'}
  already registered for file
  ComponentImpl{key='StanMIS:StanMIS:4E9625D2-557E-450C-90CC-A6B6FB57B6C9:Models/Smp/Grids/ProjectTeams/SmpProjectTeamFilterModel.cs', type=FILE, uuid='AVe_-nQKU1hbfyCkniEZ', name='', description='null', fileAttributes=FileAttributes{languageKey='cs', unitTest=false},
  reportAttributes=ReportAttributes{ref=1506, version='null',
  path='Models/Smp/Grids/ProjectTeams/SmpProjectTeamFilterModel.cs'}}.
  Unable to register OriginalFile{id=1353, uuid='1488ce7d-094c-4859-9e23-adae0f1ac2a3', key='StanMIS:StanMIS:4E9625D2-557E-450C-90CC-A6B6FB57B6C9:Models/XXX/Grids/DStanContacts/SmpDStanContactFilterModel.cs'}.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.filemove.MutableMovedFilesRepositoryImpl.setOriginalFile(MutableMovedFilesRepositoryImpl.java:41) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.registerMatches(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:144) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.execute(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:139) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=MIS | type=REPORT | id=AVe_-iOpE8SSKScA9O_3 | submitter=XXX | time=24633ms
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8013. It is fixed in version 6.1.